# My Open Office is not in increasing my productivity, how can I counter this?

Tags: productivity, offices, cubicles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any strategies you can use to remain focused when working in a open plan environment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/778/are-there-any-strategies-you-can-use-to-remain-focused-when-working-in-a-open-pl)

We have an open office (no cubical walls) that is intended to increase productivity.
However I find that the increase in distractions, both sound and visual negates this.
How can I overcome those distractions but still keep in touch with colleagues in a (fairly) open manner?

Comment: What specific problem(s) are you having? What specific benefits of the open office are important to maintain? What is your level of ability to make change?  These are all questions that need to be answered before we can suggest any solutions that will have more than a random chance to help you.

Comment: As @Chad already mentioned: Pick a distraction and focus your question on it. Depending on the nature of the distraction [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) might be the more suitable site (and they already have quite a few questions that may help solve your problems).

Comment: Experience has taught me that the best way to respond to a noisy "open office" environment is to start looking for work elsewhere. I have great difficulty being productive in such an environment, and trying day in and day out cause my clinical anxiety to act up, and exhaustion from the anxiety causes my clinical depression to act up. I don't get why  employers think this arrangement makes people "more productive". A slack channel or the like is much better way to facilitate collaboration.