# Activity Based Workplace - How to survive and thrive as an introvert?

Tags: distractions

My company has last week switched to an Activity Based Workplace. Meaning; no solitary offices, huge open spaces, no assigned desks, and the cubicles aren't even cubicles (the dividers are waist-level...).

As a big introvert, I can't focus like this. I need "tethering" in the form of having my own desk to return to every day, and I need a distraction-less environment (music in headphones only do so much - I still have people in my visual periphery at all times, as well as people walking up to me at any time during the day). My actual time spent working now is maybe 2-3 hours out of my 8 hour day. Which is insane.

How can I best address my need to have a "static" space that I can call my own in an environment like this?

EDIT: the question referenced above is not a duplicate of this one, but they overlap to such an extent that this specific question (mine) might be hard to answer better than the comments and answers that have been posted thus far.

Comment: [Are there any strategies you can use to remain focused when working in a open plan environment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/778)

Comment: I think this has the core of a good question but we need to focus it on one aspect of your issue with the activity based work-space.  For that reason I focused the question on the grounding part.  There is already the linked question on staying on task or that would have been another option

Comment: For coping strategies the linked question seems like a rather complete duplicate. If your work is so affected that you can't even handle people being within view or having people ask you stuff, perhaps that's grounds for a different question though I'm struggling to see a real answer to that other than "You'll have to fix that."

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, as an introvert, I would have quit the day they announced this horrible situation. It doesn't take a week to know that this is an unacceptable way to work when you are stressed by being around people.

Comment: Do you mean open plan office an "activity based work place" does not make sense in English

Comment: @Neuromancer It's actually a real thing: [Activity-based working](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity-based_working)

Comment: Combination of being an introvert and a software developer makes this sort of environment pure hell.  Not only are people exhausting, but the visual and audio distractions prevent any sort of real focus to solve problems.  I would immediately start a job search if my company moved to that sort of workspace.

Comment: @DavidK ah one of those HR introduced buzzword bingo policies

Comment: @JoeStrazzere We're all different, noises around me can't do anything to me (and I don't have headphones), if I'am really into something, I don't see people passing. However I would be quite annoyed to have to setup my desk everyday in a different place. I strongly like the idea to own a bit of place for myself . For the sake of objectivity and avoiding useless debate, I think we should remove the fact that OP supposed it is because of it's introvert side. That situation annoy him, what can he do ? That is enough to make a proper question.

Answer (score 12):

I also work in an activity based workplace, and I have noticed that early birds tend to occupy the same spot every day, while late comers have to deal with the leftovers.

In your case, check first your office layout: you will surely find a few spots that are suitable to your needs.

Then strive to be in the office as one of the first: you will be able to pick your spot when still plenty of them are empty.

Comment: So if you come in late you are entitled to worse space than an early riser? How disgusting.

Comment: @HLGEM, at least in my workplace late comers takes the desks closer to the coffee machine

Comment: Yes, I try to come in early. I am usually one of the first 10 people which helps a bundle.

Answer (score 3):

If you need (not want) an accommodation, then you will need a medical excuse. This is clearly causing you anxiety. I would talk first to a therapist about the problem and see if you can get him to write a note explaining that this environment is not good for you and that you need an assigned desk. By law (in the US and most probably in much of Europe) they cannot deny you a medical accommodation that is not too disruptive of the workplace.

BTW only stupid companies use this type of seating. Personally I would move on to some place that respects the needs of employees to be able to do their jobs in an environment that allows concentration and doesn't treat them as interchangeable parts.

Comment: *BTW only stupid companies use this type of seating*  - Citation needed.

Comment: I'll back HLGEM up on the stupidity assignment.

Comment: Add my vote to the stupidity assignment.  I would bet good money that overall productivity drops like a rock with these seating plans.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I think the therapist might suggest changing to a better employer

Comment: The stupidity assignment feels more like a personal complaint for a situation than a fact checked statement. I would love to see studies or any source that proves that this kind of environment is stupid.

Comment: Use this search and you will find plenty of articles on why this is stupid https://www.google.com/search?q=OPen+office+plans+and+their+negative+impacts&oq=OPen+office+plans+and+their+negative+impacts&aqs=chrome..69i57.13374j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @HLGEM, there is a differenced between static open offices, and "activity based workplace". But I guess all drawbacks from open office can be applied to activty based, adding the fact that you don't know where you will stand tomorrow and who will be your neighbour.

Comment: http://theconversation.com/the-research-on-hot-desking-and-activity-based-work-isnt-so-positive-75612

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the funny convo. Also "senior engineers, bankers, and people working in financial services...found the open-plan environment challenging, particularly when focusing on complex tasks like analyzing figures or working on documents." this is my experience so far. Multinational corp wants to be so hip and cool but doesn't even spend 5 seconds using Google before rash decisions.